# How to pass "00:00:00" if value in timespan is null?

Tags: c#, linq, null, timespan

I am trying to sum my `timespan`. My logic is working absolutely fine, he only problem is if value is `NULL` then my application breaks. I want to pass "00:00:00" as my time-span if value is `NULL`. My following code is not working:

```
@Model.Sum(x=> TimeSpan.Parse(x.Time ?? "00:00:00").Minutes)
```

`X.Time` is `string` and in my logic it could be `NULL`.If it is `NULL`, I want to replace it with 00:00:00

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `x.Time`? And are you sure you want `Minutes` rather than `TotalMinutes`? What flavour of LINQ is this - EF, LINQ to Objects, something else? Is `x` null, or is `x.Time` null? When you say it's "not working" - what exactly happens?

Comment: if x.Time is null I want it to be "00:00:00" because the data in time field is in this format.

Comment: Timespan can't be null, it's a value type. I'm guessing `x.Time` is a string, but why should I guess that? Please [edit] your question to provide the information @DaisyShipton asked for.

Comment: What is the type of `x`? Can it be null?

Comment: must be x`` since `string Time = null; Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.Parse(Time ?? "00:00:00").Minutes);` runs fine.

Comment: try with "0.00:00:00" since that is the timespan format (d.hh:mm:ss)

Comment: @wp78de: Unless it's a matter of using EF or similar and that not handling `??` properly. Unfortunately we're still missing a lot of information.

Comment: When you say null, do you mean String.Empty too?

Comment: Yes It i string and it can be NULL. X is my Lambda Expression

Comment: @SyedSafeerUlHassan `x` is not your lambda expression, it is the first parameter to your expression.

Comment: The code presented in the OP works fine if `x.Time` is null. There must be something else going on here that we're not being told about. Perhaps `x` itself is null?

Comment: I'm guessing that this would work: `Model.Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x?.Time ?? "00:00:00").Minutes);` (assuming that `x` OR `x.Time` could be null).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to sum the total of minutes, so you can simply check for null and add 0 to the total amount:

```
@Model.Sum(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Time) ? TimeSpan.Parse(x.Time).TotalMinutes : 0)
```

Comment: I think your query is not performant. Instead of checking all values, filtering before will be more efficiant.

Comment: No, it has to filter either way. The performance difference is negligible. Did you run it? @CoskunOzogul

Comment: @CoskunOzogul And it is not very nice to downvote the user that tried to help you on your answer.

Comment: You are right for downvote, I am sorry. I upvoted. But for the performance story, it depends on the size of the list. It can be important.

Comment: No, my answer filters too, but in a single  step. The worst thing happening is that  it adds 0. The CLR must be smart enough to void that action.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking all values null or not, you can filter before in order to have only not null values.

```
@Model.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Time)).Sum(x=> TimeSpan.Parse(x.Time).Minutes)
```

Comment: It is a string, and string doesn't have a `HasValue` property.

Comment: `?? "00:00:00"` is useless here.

Comment: Right, I removed it

Comment: Please explain more than "what about this". What did you do? Why did it help?

Answer (score 1):

The `TimeSpan.Parse` method [expects a parameter in the form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]
```

since `00:00:00` is a valid input string, I'm taking a wild guess here and say that it's not about `null` values, but rather the error occurs when your `x.Time` was set by `DateTime.Now.ToString()` etc. because in those cases you get the

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.'

Your code works perfectly fine for `Time` being `null`. Please make sure the other values are valid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your question is that from what you say, the code should work. For example, the following code works correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    class Test
    {
        public string Time;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var Model = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test{Time = "01:01:01"},
                // null, // Uncomment this line to make it crash.
                new Test{Time = null}, 
                new Test{Time = "02:02:02"}
            };

            int result = Model.Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x.Time ?? "00:00:00").Minutes);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you say an error is occurring, there must be something else going wrong. I think that the issue is that `x` itself is null.

We can demonstrate that possibility by uncommenting the indicated line. If you do that, the program will crash.

If that is indeed the problem, then the solution is very simple; just change the summation to:

```
int result = Model.Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x?.Time ?? "00:00:00").Minutes);
```

After making that change, a null `x` will not make it crash.

Note that it may be slightly better to write:

```
int result = Model.Sum(x => x?.Time != null ? TimeSpan.Parse(x.Time).Minutes : 0 );
```

because then you avoid parsing `"00:00:00"` only to return zero (via `.Minutes`), but the difference is likely to be very marginal if any.

Comment: +1 nice answer, especially the part about the unknown exception. It's really hard to tell what the error is when it's not stated in the question; e.g. you and Pervez assume a `NullReferenceException`, I assume a `FormatException` but in the end, unless OP edit's their answer, we can never know.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow You're right - it could be a `FormatException`. The question is really a bit too iffy to answer, but hopefully one of these answers will elicit more information from the OP!

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting a null exception because `x` is `null`. So when you call the property `x.Time`, it will throw a `NullReferenceException`. You can use the ternary operator to check if `x` is `null`

```
 @Model.Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x == null ? "00:00:00" : x.Time).Minutes)
```

Comment: No, he is not getting a NRE. Nowhere in the question it says so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

TimeSpan? variable = (TimeSpan?)null.

This value return null value.